# Error al usar onAuthStateChange con react router dom

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom, firebase-auth

al usar `onAuthStateChanged` con un el hook useState el valor no cambia, el estado del hook siempre es el mismo, siendo que dentro del authstatechange si cambia.

mando mi codigo.

## ProtectedRoutes.jsx

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const auth = getAuth();

export default function ProtectedRoutes() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        setUser(user);
    });
    console.log(user)
    return (user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />);
}
```

ese user es el que me devuelve en null siendo que si pongo un console log dentro no es null, agradecería la ayuda.
saludos

Comment: intenta que el onAuthStateChange esté dentro de un useEffect, creo que así te funcionaría